# Why does using std::vector<> instead of std::list<> cause an increase in code size?

Tags: c++, stl

In a project at work a lot std::list and std::vector are used. Since random inserts were seldom needed, I started to change the std::lists to std::vectors. But with every switch the resulting code size increased (not a fixed amount but roughly 1kB on average). Given that std::vector was already used, I don't see why switching a std::list to std::vector should increase the code size. Any ideas why? The compiler used is g++.

Comment: Code size means source size, or executable/binary size?

Comment: Is this a debug or release build?

Comment: ...because the linker has to put 2 extra letters in the binary (vector - 6 character, list - 4 character)

Comment: @Nawaz, I mean the size of the executable binary.

Comment: @MarceloCantos It's a release build.

Comment: Question is too vague as is, should contain a minimal testcase that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have added a vector of a new type (e.g. In your original code you used `vector<int>` and now you added a `vector<string>`: they are different types, so the code size will increase to include the new type).

Comment: No, the objects in the containers are of the same type, of course.

Comment: @frank: some code would help, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in debug mode? If yes, it could be inlined range checking code that increases the code size. Note that this is not so much necessary for lists, where you only need to check if the next node is null.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, without further details we can only guess.

The vector-memory is contiguous (which is guaranteed by the standard), but list-memory is not. Therefore it might be that the compiler is able to vectorize and unroll your vector-based code better, which leads to bigger instructions and longer binary code.

Answer (score -1):

std::vector contains more functions and code than list (no random access in list)

Comment: Unused code is usually left out of the executable (optimization).

Comment: yes, but the implementation of the common operations might be more complex since the vector functions might need to handle situations which cannot occur in a list

Comment: or due to handling a more complex internal data structure

Comment: `std::vector` may have the __simplest__ internal data structure. It's a contiguous block of memory, both `operator[]` and random-access iterators just use address arithmetic.